# General Guidelines and Tips for using Induction

Tags: usage, recommendations, induction

There are many kinds of induction (induction over the natural numbers ⊂ structural induction ⊂ Noetherian induction), when do I use which flavour? And what should I keep in mind when doing proofs by induction?

Simple example: I have an inductively defined predicate `EVEN` and a function `even`. Now I want to show completeness and soundness, ie. `EVEN x ⟹ even x` and `even x ⟹ EVEN x`. What kind of induction do I use for each?

---

Are there some general guidelines I can follow? Sometimes, we need to strengthen induction hypothesis or generalize variables (Coq's `generalize` or Isabelle's `arbitrary`). When and how do I use simultaneous induction on different well-founded partial orders?

I understand that there is no general principle that always applies, but are there some heuristics I can follow to develop an intuition?

When transferring a pen-and-paper proof to a specific proof assistant, are there any quirks or things to keep in mind?

Answer (score 3):

The best guideline is: If you don't know how to do the proof on pen-and-paper, you probably will get lost doing it in a proof assistant.  If you don't know what your induction hypothesis is *supposed* to be, you will probably struggle to find the right one when working in a proof assistant.

That said, the next best guideline, I've found, is that (almost) everything is fundamentally structural induction.  If you want to use a different form of induction (such as well-founded recursion), I've found it useful to be aware that it's using structural recursion under the hood.

To address your concrete examples:

> Simple example: I have an inductively defined predicate EVEN and a function even. Now I want to show completeness and soundness, ie. EVEN x ⟹ even x and even x ⟹ EVEN x. What kind of induction do I use for each?

When proving `EVEN x ⟹ even x`, you can either induct on `EVEN x`, or you can induct on `x` and then invert your proof of `EVEN x`; both will work equally well.  When proving `even x ⟹ EVEN x`, the only thing you can do is induct on `x`.

> When and how do I use simultaneous induction on different well-founded partial orders?

I'm not sure what you're asking here.  You do simultaneous induction on different well-founded partial orders if that's what the pen-and-paper proof needs to go through.  As for *how*, my impulse is that you want to combine the two partial orders into a single partial-order on the cartesian product of the types, and prove this single partial order well-founded.  You could do a nested induction/fixpoint, which is powerful and convenient, but almost never needed.